# Cucumber test with Selenium and Ruby in Jenkins server fails but passes in local machine

Tags: ruby, selenium, jenkins, cucumber, headless

I have some cucumber tests made using the gem 'cucumber-rails'.

This tests use another gem called 'page-objects' (from cheezy) and in my tests I use Selenium and Chrome-driver.

To make the tests run in the Jenkins server (that has no X) I use the gem 'headless' and I've configured the server to use Xfvb (my local machine runs Elementary OS Freya 0.3.2 and the server runs Ubuntu 15.10).

When I run these tests in my local machine (also using headless), **they all pass flawlessly** every time. The same happens **when I run the tests in Jenkins' server from the Terminal**.

But **when I run them on Jenkins CI, some fail** (the error is "didn't find an element" - when the element is there).

Both tests fail because it cannot find an element (the element exists and when it fails I print the screen just to check what's happening. The page print show that it is on the right page and displays the element).

The strange thing is that they both fail at the second step (the first one is going to the login page and authenticate, which it does correctly). Also, there's another test that runs first that always passes (the tests have pretty much the same structure).

Both tests run over the same server (the webpage they access is the same and the data is the same).

I have looked at this over and over and I can't find any explanation. I know the problem is not very detailed, so if there's anything missing that might be important, just tell me and I'll update the post.

If you happen to know any reason why the tests might fail on a 'Xless' server, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks a lot for the help!

---

Edit:
The failures are both "element not found" and the element is present.

I've also made the Jenkins user part of the sudoers.
Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I would start trouble shooting file permissions.

My experience tells me that file permissions is a complicated issue that can give you many interesting failures on a Linux box. 

When you executed the tests manually on the Jenkins box, did you run as Jenkns? In the same directory as Jenkins would have done it?

Comment: Yes, I ran the tests on the terminal using the Jenkins user and on the same folder as the Jenkins CI does.  Should I give root permissions to the Jenkins user?

Comment: I've seen window size be an issue in similar setups. Try setting the Selenium window size to be large enough that the elements you're interested in are on screen.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth, I thought about it as well, but I just made the window really large so that it shows on the canvas but I get the same error :\

Comment: I would not give the Jenkins user root permissions. I would make sure that the Jenkins user had just the right permissions and nothing extra. Possibly including it in a group or two. It depends on the needs. But never root.

Comment: I gave it root just to test if it made a difference, but it didn't. The problem is not with Jenkins user (as the Jenkins user can run the tests successfully in the terminal). The problem seems to be with the Jenkins CI. :\

Comment: How did you get the terminal?  Did you "xterm" or an ssh from another terminal without  X ?

Comment: Can you try grabbing the element in a different way? Are you sure that Jenkins CI is running with the same gems as you do when you run it from the terminal? You could potentially stand up a windows VM and have Jenkins kick off the tests there. This would allow you to see the tests as they run, which could be useful in situations like this.

Comment: @Jayan, I connect to the server through ssh.

Comment: @Tyler, the tests pass on the same machine with the same code, so I'm assuming that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out the problem and the solution.

The problem was that the elements were still not loaded when performing their lookup. The solution was to use PageObject.wait_until to wait for them.

I realized that this was the problem after noticing the errors were sometimes these ones: [Stale Element Reference](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp)

But there's a question that remains, still: why does this only happen in Jenkins CI? (whoever finds the solution will earn the bounty :) )

Comment: Your machine is probably more performant so it probably loads the elements faster. You should always wait for elements so the test doesn't fail depending how fast is the machine / internet

Answer (score 3):

The only way to solve these issues is to debug the error received. To debug, we can add screenshots at different places in the scenario to identify the cause of the failure. If this is failing as page not completely loaded, then to solve this issue, is to increase the default wait time to open the particular page or to locate an element. Once the page loads or element is located, set the default time to its original value.

Example: 
1. You can add screen shot in you scenario:

```
Scenario: Click on Sign In Link
Given Joe opens "www.yahoo.com" page
When Joe takes screenshot with file name "ScreenShot1"
When Joe clicks "Sign In" link
```

The second line "When Joe takes screenshot with file name "ScreenShot1" can be used to take the screen shot

```
And(/^(\S*) takes screenshot with file name "([^"]*)"$/) do |user, file_name|
  takes_screenshot_with_file_name(file_name, "ScreenShot")
end

def takes_screenshot_with_file_name(file_name, message)
  page.save_screenshot("../../target/#{file_name}.png", :full => true)
end
```

2. Default wait time can be increased in below mentioned way:

The second line "And Joe waits for "Sign In" link" can be used to increase the default wait time

```
Scenario: Click on Sign In Link
Given Joe opens "www.yahoo.com" page
And Joe waits for "Sign In" link
When Joe clicks "Sign In" link

And(/^Joe waits for "([^"]*)" link$/) do |linkName|
  Capybara.default_wait_time = 120
  page.should have_content(linkName)
  Capybara.default_wait_time = DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME
end
```

Comment: Hi Sarabjit! Thanks for helping. I'm not using Capybara at all, but I already have the screenshot taken, and it shows that the user is at the correct page where the element should be (thought I can't see it, cause the element is at the bottom of the page and the only thing printed is the top of the browser! I'm going to update the description with a picture of an error! Also, the ":full => true" is a good tip!

Comment: @Tiago - Which language you are using? I will try to help you in that. You just need to add screenshot

Comment: it's Ruby. I uploaded a screenshot on the original post :)

Comment: @Tiago - Can you try with scrolling to bottom before clicking the element? Like : 

page.execute_script("$('.modal-body-overlay').scrollTop(300)")

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have stopped trying for a few days. I'll do it later, again, and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Try with page.execute_script("$('.modal-body-overlay').scrollBottom(300)") not Top :)

Comment: @Tiago Does scrolling helps?

Comment: I've even maximized the window so that everything would fit on the screen, but it made no difference!

Answer (score 2):

Things you can try:

Reduce the test to the very basics: Instead of running it all, just that concrete page and try to find that element. Check if that works. It probably won't...but you can pinpoint better the problem.

Add some waits in the code (`sleep <number of seconds>`), to see if your code is trying to find something "too fast". This happens time to time.

Instead of using headless, try to use something else and run it in a browser (with some gems like capybara you can switch between headless, firefox or chrome).

Can you find some sort of JS logs, to see if there are any errors?

Do Jenkins and your environment have exactly the same gem versions?

Another thing you can do to debug it is use something like `byebug` and set a breakpoint just before it fails. You can then use the interactive console to inspect the page, and run different commands to try to find the element. You would have to do this while in jenkins, but as a last resort...

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Well, I changed the test just so it would have two steps, and it still fails in the same thing. I can't run the test without headless as the Jenkins server doesn't have an X. The environment is the same (I run the tests in the terminal over the Jenkins CI folder).